# Using a variable 'that is in Class' in another page in Python

Tags: python, function, class, oop

I am new at programming. So to improve myself I am trying to build up something.
So my question is:

```
class smallwavesincurrency:
    def __init__(self,username,userpassowrd,url):
        self.username = username
        self.userpasword = userpassword
        self.url = url
        self.usd = self.usdcurrency()

    def usdcurrency(self):
        #There is beautifulsoup process here. I did not put them to avoid infollution#
        return usd #End of the function I return that variable.
```

I can use the variable as "self.usd" in my class without any problem and it works.
But I need to import it into another page in class.
I tried this:

```
#This codes were written in another page:
from filename import smallwavesincurrency
class something:
    def __init__(self):
        usdfromanotherpage = smallwavesincurrency.usdcurrency()
```

When I want to use it, the error I got is "usdcurrency missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

If you help me, I would be appreciated.

Mercii

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Thank you :) I am new here as well. I could not get used to stackoverflow yet :). But my problem does not occur because of the indentation

Comment: But without correct indentation we can't tell that. Shall I edit your question for you?

Comment: Thank you. I tried to edit it. If you see any problem. Please edit :)

Comment: So does the `usdcurrency()` method use the `username` and `password` attributes?

Comment: No, usdcurrency() does not use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `usdcurrency()` is an instance method, you need to call the method on an object, in this case, a `smallwavesincurrency` object. Thus, you would have to call the `__init__()` method first.

There are three different ways (off the top of my head) which you can do this, ranked in order of my personal recommendation:

1. Create a `smallwavesincurrency` object, then call the `usdcurrency()` method

```py
from filename import smallwavesincurrency

class something:
     def __init__(self):
        self.swic = smallwavesincurrency(username, userpassword, url)
        usdfromanotherpage = self.swic.usdcurrency()
```

2. Call the `__init__()` and `usdcurrency()` method at the same time.

```py
from filename import smallwavesincurrency

class something:
     def __init__(self):
        usdfromanotherpage = smallwavesincurrency(
            username, userpassword, url
        ).usdcurrency()
```

3. Pass a `smallwavesincurrency` object to the `usdcurrency()` method.

```py
from filename import smallwavesincurrency

class something:
     def __init__(self):
        usdfromanotherpage = smallwavesincurrency.usdcurrency(
            smallwavesincurrency(username, userpassword, url)
        )
```

Comment: btw you are creating instances of `smallwavesincurrency` without supplying the required parameters.

Comment: @quamrana I did that on purpose because I'm assuming that providing arguments is implied, but I will edit it, just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it could become a static method?

```py
class smallwavesincurrency:
    def __init__(self, username, userpassowrd, url):
        self.username = username
        self.userpasword = userpassword
        self.url = url
        self.usd = self.usdcurrency()

    @staticmethod
    def usdcurrency():
        #There is beautifulsoup process here. I did not put them to avoid infollution#
        return usd #End of the function I return that variable.
```

Comment: No, it is not. When I tried to use staticmethod, I cannot use some features which comes from other methods

Comment: So, can *those* methods also become static?

Comment: Actually all of them are connected to each other. The class connect a website and the website has its own currency. So first it gets the currency then I scrape some informations and another method calculate them by the currency and the information that was scraped. So every method has their own function.

Comment: Ok, so what happened when you made them all static?

Comment: If I change it as staticmethod as you said, It would be better. So I am changing it. Thank you for your helps.